# How Interface is resolved in MvvmCross

Tags: c#, logging, interface, mvvmcross

In .Core project I have an interface for logging:

```
 public interface ILogger
{
    void Trace(string format, params object[] args);
    .........
    void Fatal(string format, params object[] args);
}
```

Which is used in a log service interface:

```
public interface ILogService
{
    ILogger GetLogger(string name);
    ILogger GetLogger(Type typeName);
    ILogger GetLogger<T>();
}
```

In .Droid project that interface is implemented:

```
 public class AndroidLogService : ILogService
{
    public ILogger GetLogger(string name)
    {
        return new AndroidLogger(name);
    }

    public ILogger GetLogger(Type typeName)
    {
        return GetLogger(typeName.Name);
    }

    public ILogger GetLogger<T>()
    {
        return GetLogger(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

In .Droid Setup.cs file AndroidLogService is registered:

```
 Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<ILogService, AndroidLogService>();
 Mvx.LazyConstructAndRegisterSingleton<IFileService, AndroidFileService>();
```

and finally used in some file in .Droid project:

```
 private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public AndroidFileService(IContextService contextService, ILogService logService, IEncryptionService encryptionService)
    {
        _logger = logService.GetLogger<AndroidFileService>();
        .......
    }
```

Finally logs work like this:

```
_logger.Warn("Failed to retrieve logo. Error: {0}", ex);
```

My doubts and questions:
AndroidFileService is never called with params that described above but from MvvmCross docs I've read that it's called [Construction Injection](https://www.mvvmcross.com/documentation/fundamentals/inversion-of-control-ioc#constructor-injection)

Ok, I understand this part but one thing is dark for me: 
Where ILogger implementation exists?
I didn't find in the whole solution any part with something like

```
Mvx.RegisterType<ILogger , SomeLogger>();
```

How it can be? What a mechanism is used to register ILogger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

I went inside AndroidLogService in Setup.cs:

```
    public class AndroidLogService : ILogService
{
    public ILogger GetLogger(string name)
    {
        return new AndroidLogger(name);
    }

    public ILogger GetLogger(Type typeName)
    {
        return GetLogger(typeName.Name);
    }

    public ILogger GetLogger<T>()
    {
        return GetLogger(typeof(T));
    }
}
```

Then I went inside AndroidLogger:

```
using NLog;
using ILogger = ....Services.Support.ILogger;//from .Core project
namespace ....Android.Services.Support//from .Droid project
{
public class AndroidLogger : ILogger
{
    private readonly NLog.ILogger _logger;

    public AndroidLogger(string name)
    {
        _logger = LogManager.GetLogger(name);
    }
    .................
```

where I see that is used NLog which is built-in implementation of ILogger.

So, when the build was created for android I inserted this snippet in 2 files: one from .Core project and another from .Droid

```
_logger = logService.GetLogger<SomeViewModel>();
String name = logService.GetType().Name;
_logger.Debug("LogService name = {0} ", name);
```

which resulted for both cases as LogService name = AndroidLogService.

Before this check I thought that as .Core project doesn't have any reference to .Droid project, so, there are different implementations for them, but I was wrong:
Interface implemented in .Droid/.iOs project also works for .Core project.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if ILogger has an implementation in MvvmCross you would get the object populated.
 `var logger  = Mvx.Resolve<ILogger>();`